# Is it possible to check specific drivers installed or not in a client computer through the php programming

Tags: php, windows, driver, installed-applications

I want to check specific drivers installed or not in a client's computer through the PHP, Is it possible with the PHP programming?

If it's possible, How can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no general interface for this indeed, as PHP is a server side language, and you want to find out things on the client side. The only possibility is to either have a client side installable extension or alter the drive to expose itself through some kind of browser interface if you have control over the driver.